# AddMicrosoftIdentityConsentHandler with Blazor .net 8

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, .net-8.0

I am puzzled as to how to incorporate AddMicrosoftIdentityConsentHandler with Blazor .net 8 application template.

The aim is to get a Blazor app to work with downstream API based on B2C authentication (which is a side-effect and beyond the focus of this post). anyway - ultimately i need to inject AddMicrosoftIdentityConsentHandler at some point inside the Blazor app.

all documentation references mention that AddMicrosoftIdentityConsentHandler is added via this line:

```
services.AddServerSideBlazor().AddMicrosoftIdentityConsentHandler();
```

however, as part of this article: [Migrate from ASP.NET Core in .NET 7 to .NET 8](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/70-80?view=aspnetcore-8.0&tabs=visual-studio)

it mentions that `builder.Services.AddServerSideBlazor()`; is to be removed and to be replaced by a call to `AddInteractiveServerComponents()`;

i can't get my head around what would be the correct path of adding AddMicrosoftIdentityConsentHandler in this scenario.

Answer (score 1):

Just it replace with

```
builder.Services.AddRazorComponents()
    .AddInteractiveServerComponents()
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityConsentHandler();
```

package `Microsoft.Identity.Web`